# How to get Current Site Country flag using Sitecore SXA?

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client

Is it possible to get flag and country name associated with each site using Sitecore SXA. I need to dispaly country flag as well as country name side by side on top of the page for each SXA Site.

Thanks

Comment: I don't recall there being an out-of-the-box component to get that type of information. But you could build a custom sxa component to retrieve that information.